# DS1820B only returns -127

Tags: ds18b20

ive used one DS1820B sensor in a AVR bread board circuit and it works there, now i tried attaching it to a arduino mega board with the code below and also another library below that.

currently the data pin is connected to pin 10 on the arduino board, but i also tried pin 2 as in this picture:

https://lastminuteengineers.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Wiring-Multiple-DS18B20-Temperature-Sensors-With-Arduino.png

i changed: #define ONE_WIRE_BUS 10   accordingly.

So after that i put the chip back onto the bread board and it still works.
I also tried it with the 4.7k resistor on the data line as pullup....still -127.

Any ideas?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
/********************************************************************/
// First we include the libraries
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
/********************************************************************/
// Data wire is plugged into pin 2 on the Arduino 
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 10
/********************************************************************/
// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices  
// (not just Maxim/Dallas temperature ICs) 
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS); 
/********************************************************************/
// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature. 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
/********************************************************************/ 

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
 sensors.begin(); 
}


void loop() {

  Serial.print("Temperature is: "); 
 Serial.print(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0)); // Why "byIndex"?  
   // You can have more than one DS18B20 on the same bus.  
   // 0 refers to the first IC on the wire 
   delay(1000); 


}
```

second code:

```
#include "DS18B20Events.h"

// Pin for DS18B20
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 10

/********************************************************************/
// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices  
// (not just Maxim/Dallas temperature ICs) 
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Init DallasTemperature
DallasTemperature dallasTemperature(&oneWire);

//Init thermometer with index 0 (default)
DS18B20Events thermometer(0);

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  DS18B20Events::setup(&dallasTemperature); // Link DS18B20Events to DallasTemperature object
  DS18B20Events::setInterval(5000); // Set min interval in milliseconds between 2 measurements. Default 10000 set in setup() method.

  // subscribe to temperature changed event
  thermometer.onChange = temperatureChanged;
}

// the loop function runs over and over again until power down or reset
void loop() {
  thermometer.loop(); // Mandatory to measure temperature and fire an event if needed

  Serial.print(thermometer.getTempC()); // Get last measured tempC if needed.
  Serial.print(" measured ");
  Serial.print((millis() - thermometer.getMillis()) / 1000);
  Serial.println(" seconds ago.");

  delay(1000);
}

void temperatureChanged(uint8_t index, float tempC)
{
  Serial.print(tempC);
  Serial.print(" new tempC at index ");
  Serial.println(index);
}
```

Comment: Please post a photo of your wiring (including a clear view of the stripes on your pullup resistor).

Comment: You need a photo of your ACTUAL wiring to your Arduino, not the Fritzing diagram of what your wiring should look like.

Comment: Im not sure what it was, but its working now with the second code. the first one is probably right too. Maybe i was just to cool(-127C) a few hours ago...oh no. Theres probably a stackoverflow page for that too.

Comment: you probably forgot pull up resistor

Comment: I found this page because I was having a similar problem. I was trying to attach to an ESP01. I was unable to get it to read on GPIO3, GPIO1 or GPIO0 but I was able to get it to work with GPIO2. It seems it may be quite sensitive to the pullup resistance.

Answer (score 1):

127 error is a **connection error**, check the wiring:

[image]